# Removing duplicates from a series based on a symmetric matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and have been unable to find a succinct solution to the following problem.

Say I have a Series of data based on a symmetric (distance)matrix, what is the most efficient way to drop duplicates from the following series?

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame([[0, 1, 2],
                [1, 0, 3],
                [2, 3, 0]], 
               index=['a', 'b', 'c'], 
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
ser = df.stack()
ser

a  a    0
   b    1
   c    2
b  a    1
   b    0
   c    3
c  a    2
   b    3
   c    0
```

What I want to do is remove duplicate pairs, since the matrix is symmetric. The output should look like this

```
a  a     0
   b     1
   c     2
b  b     0
   c     3
c  c     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code runs faster than the currently accepted answer:

```
import numpy as np

def dm_to_series1(df):
    df = df.astype(float)
    df.values[np.triu_indices_from(df, k=1)] = np.nan
    return df.unstack().dropna()
```

The type of the `DataFrame` is converted to `float` so that elements can be nulled with `np.nan`. In practice, a distance matrix would probably already store floats so this step may not be strictly necessary. The upper triangle (excluding the diagonal) is nulled and these entries are removed after converting the `DataFrame` to a `Series`.

I adapted the currently accepted solution in order to compare runtimes. Note that I updated it to use a set instead of a list for faster runtime:

```
def dm_to_series2(df):
    ser = df.stack()

    seen = set()
    for tup in ser.index.tolist():
        if tup[::-1] in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(tup)

    return ser[seen]
```

Testing the two solutions on the original example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2],
                   [1, 0, 3],
                   [2, 3, 0]], 
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

My solution:

```
In [4]: %timeit dm_to_series1(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 538 µs per loop
```

@Marius' solution:

```
In [5]: %timeit dm_to_series2(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 816 µs per loop
```

I also tested against a larger distance matrix by randomly generating a 50x50 matrix using scikit-bio's `skbio.stats.distance.randdm` function and converting that to a `DataFrame`:

```
from skbio.stats.distance import randdm
big_dm = randdm(50)
big_df = pd.DataFrame(big_dm.data, index=big_dm.ids, columns=big_dm.ids)
```

My solution:

```
In [7]: %timeit dm_to_series1(big_df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 649 µs per loop
```

@Marius' solution:

```
In [8]: %timeit dm_to_series2(big_df)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.61 ms per loop
```

Note that my solution may not be as memory-efficient as @Marius' solution because I'm creating a copy of the input `DataFrame` and making modifications to it. If it is acceptable to modify the input `DataFrame`, the code could be updated to be more memory-efficient by using in-place `DataFrame` operations.

Note: my solution was inspired by the answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14129979/3776794).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how efficient this is, but this works:

```
seen = []

for tup in ser.index.tolist():
    if tup[::-1] in seen:
        continue
    seen.append(tup)

ser_reduced = ser[seen]

ser_reduced
Out[9]: 
a  a    0
   b    1
   c    2
b  b    0
   c    3
c  c    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, this does solve my problem. I was hoping that there was a 'pandas' way to achieve this as the distance matrices can be quite large. But this works well.