# Pandas - removing symmetrical duplicates in two rows from a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have the following dataframe of flows between countries:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['US','FR', 10,'a'], ['FR','US', 15,'b'], ['IT','BA', 14,'c']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country_1', 'Country_2','var_1','var_2']) 
print(df)
  Country_1 Country_2  var_1 var_2
0        US        FR     10     12
1        FR        US     12     10
2        IT        BA     14     5
```

It is symmetrical in the sense that all pairs of countries are seen two times. My goal is to eliminate symmetrical duplicates based on the two columns **Country_1** and **Country_2**.  In this example, the expected dataframe would like:

```
  Country_1 Country_2  var_1 var_2
0        US        FR     10     12
1        IT        BA     14     5
```

One related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876906/removing-duplicates-from-a-series-based-on-a-symmetric-matrix-in-pandas) deals with the unidimensional case but the solution doesn't work when there is a large number of variables (var_11, var_12; var_21, var_22; var_31, var_32;...).

Has someone faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#first remove all duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Country_1','Country_2'])

#sorted values in country columns and remove duplicates
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Country_1','Country_2']], axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()

df = df[~m]
print (df)
  Country_1 Country_2  var_1 var_2
0        US        FR     10     a
2        IT        BA     14     c
```